# MouseMove works, MouseDown does not. WPF XAML

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I made Button in Xaml. I would like to fire MouseDown event:

```
    MouseDown="Button_MouseDown_1"
```

I implemented this method in codeBehind, but it doesn't work.
But if I implement this method:

```
    MouseMove="Button_MouseMove_1"
```

Implementation works. 
Where is the problem ?

Seba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Button element itself is handling the mouse down event before your event handler gets called - meaning your event handler wont get called.

More than likely what you're actually wanting to implement is the Click event though (e.g.):

```
Click="button1_Click"
```

This will respond to the button getting clicked by the mouse or if it has focus and enter is pressed etc...

But if you really do need to specifically implement a handler for the mousedown event on the button you can use the PreviewMouseDown event which your handler will be notified of.

[MSDN: Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) can give more detail of how routed events work.