# How to access one object or control on MouseDown event on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Last method doesn't work. `obj` is created on the canvas but the MouseDown doesn't work.

```
obj = new C_Rectangle(); 
obj.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(obj_MouseDown);
myCtrl.Children.Add(obj); 

void obj_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name: " + sender.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What is C_Rectangle?

Comment: c_rectangle is class for draw rectangle by drawing Visual.

Comment: this code add to myCtr1(canvas object) in the main page.

Answer (score 0):

By default rectangle is not filled. you must fill your rectangle by a color like blue to your code works.

Comment: No, i can fill rectangle and move it by hit Testing.but object mouse down is not work.

Comment: object have obj.Draw(myCtrl) method( draw and fill it).

Comment: '    public void DrawS(DrawingVisual dVisual, Point dPoint)
        {
            try
            {
                Brush brush = Brushes.Red;
                Pen drawingPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5);

                using (DrawingContext dc = dVisual.RenderOpen())
                {
                    dc.DrawRectangle(brush, drawingPen, new Rect(dPoint, new Size(40, 40)));
                }
                C_Surface.hits.Add(dVisual);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }'

Comment: your problem is not about Button. See [mousemove works mousedown does not wpf xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961084/mousemove-works-mousedown-does-not-wpf-xaml)

Comment: you can use 'PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' event